# My vector prints all elements but last one c++

Tags: c++

This is making no sense to me. I do something to the code and it works only the first time. I then test it again and it goes back to not including the last element in the vector. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help.

```
cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;

getline(cin, sentence);

for (auto x : sentence) // stores individual words in the vector
{
    if (x == ' ')
    {
        myString.push_back(word);
        cout << word << endl;
        word = " ";
    }
    else
    {
        word = word + x;

    }

}
for (auto elem : myString)
{
    cout << elem << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scanning the `sentence` one letter at a time, appending each letter to `word` until you encounter a space, and only then are you inserting the `word` into the `vector`.  So, if the `sentence` does not end with a space, the last `word` won't be inserted into the `vector`.

There are a few different ways you can fix that:

1. check if `word` is not empty after the loop exits, and if not then insert it into the vector:

```cpp
cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;

getline(cin, sentence);

for (auto x : sentence)
{
    if (isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(x))
    {
        if (!word.empty())
        {
            myString.push_back(word);
            word = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        word += x;
    }
}

if (!word.empty())
{
    myString.push_back(word);
}

for (const auto &elem : myString)
{
    cout << elem << endl;
}
```

2. Scan for word boundaries yourself, such as with `string::find_first_(not_)of()`:

```cpp
cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;

getline(cin, sentence);

const char* wspace = " \f\n\r\t\v";

size_t start = 0, end;
while ((start = sentence.find_first_not_of(wspace, start)) != string::npos)
{
    end = sentence.find_first_of(wspace, start + 1));
    if (end == string::npos)
    {
        myString.push_back(sentence.substr(start));
        break;
    }

    myString.push_back(sentence.substr(start, end-start));
    start = end + 1;
}

for (const auto &elem : myString)
{
    cout << elem << endl;
}
```

3. put the `sentence` into a `std::istringstream` and then use `operator>>` to extract complete whitespace-separate words from it. Let the standard library do all the heavy parsing for you:

```cpp
cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;

getline(cin, sentence);

istringstream iss(sentence);
while (iss >> word)
{
    myString.push_back(word);
}

for (const auto &elem : myString)
{
    cout << elem << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no space after the last word, you are not adding it to your vector.

Comment: Space... The final frontier...